Ionic App Consumes High RAM Memory After Running for 3 Hours – How Can I Reduce Memory Usage?
I'm working on an Ionic app that has a memory consumption issue. After running for about three hours, the app’s RAM usage rises to 2.5 GB, which significantly affects performance. I’ve tried several approaches to manage memory, but the issue persists. Here are some details about my setup:
Framework: Ionic with Angular and used firebase for second display
Platform: Android POS
How can I identify or reduce memory usage in my app to avoid these high RAM spikes? Are there any recommended tools or best practices specific to Ionic apps that can help?
Any advice or insight into resolving this would be much appreciated!
